# Using autolayout constraints to define height minus a constant with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to have a View with autolayout , such that the subview has equal height with parent minus a constant?

The Hierarchy is UIView > UIScrollVIew > UITableView. The view is also embedded in a UINavigationController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You simply pin the subview to the top and bottom of its super view with the constant set to the offset you wish.

As the outside view changes, the inner view will change to match and maintain the offset. You will need to set left and right constraints as well using the same mechanism.

**Edit after discussion:**

The UIScrollView needs to know the size of your content. You can not simply use auto layout without a few adjustments.

Assumption is your view layout is:

UIViewController -> UIScrollView -> UIView -> UITableView

For your UIView, pin the top, bottom, left and right to the UIScrollView.

To see things properly in storyboard you also seem to have to center the UIView horizontally and vertically. Once you add this you should see the content fill the scroll view bar any edge offsets you set in your pinning.

Pin your UITable to the UIView top, bottom, left and right.

You are going to have to adjust the width in your code somehow to the size you want to scroll horizontally.

Comment: Autolayout is giving me a headache , i add "Top Space to container" and "Bottom space to Container" but i see no effect

Comment: Only if i set "Equal Height" constrain i see effect. Is there a way to add a constant in that equal height margin?

Comment: I notice you said you have a UIScrollView. The UITableView will scroll for you, so I do not think you need it. That may also be causing your problem. Just add the UITableView directly into your UIViewController and lay it out there relative to any other items you have.

Comment: I need the UIScrollView for horizontal scrolling in UITableView. Or is there a way for horizontal scrolling in UITableView ? I know this is not really aligned with apple HID but the UITableView has to have a horizontal scrolling

Comment: Had a play and found how to do this. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you now it works , and you helped me understand the issue!

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder:

1. Clear constraints on your subview
2. Select your subview
3. Choose Pin in right bottom corner of IB view
4. Select bottom pin and enter your constant (I entered 30), select top pin and enter 0.
5. Select other constraints if needed.
6. Accept with button Add x constraints
   [image]

Comment: I have a UITableView as a subview and it does take any effect. It its a child of a UIScrollVIew and a UIView. The view is also embedded in a UINavigationController

Comment: @iamIcarus - why do you embedding UITableView in UIScrollView. UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. I would suggest you to create hierarchy: UIView(1) -> UIView(2) -> UITableView, and treat (2) view as a Subview at the screenshot and setup constraints as I proposed.